# nohup process not persisting between ssh sessions

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, aws, nohup

I have an ubuntu server on AWS EC2.  I can access it, with Putty and ssh, from a Windows 7 laptop.
I would like to start a process up during one of these ssh sessions and have it continue after I have ended the ssh session.  I thought that this could be done with nohup.  However I try the following command on one ssh session.

```
nohup /var/www/Executables/inotifydropboxcopy &
```

I then do

```
ps | grep inotify
```

I get

```
27554 pts/0    00:00:00 inotifydropboxcopy
```

However, when I open a new ssh session, to the same server,  and type

```
ps | grep inotify
```

I get nothing.  I also get nothing when I end the ssh session and start another.

How do I start a process that continues, on the server, between ssh sessions?

Edit:

I went into screen

```
screen
```

entered

```
 /var/www/Executables/inotifydropboxcopy &
```

Then detached from screen with ctrl-ad

Then, on the initial ssh session

```
ps | grep inotify
```

returned

```
27554 pts/0    00:00:00 inotifydropboxcopy
```

But, when I started up a new ssh session and entered

```
ps | grep inotify
```

I got nothing.

Comment: Use `screen` instead

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have edited my question to say what happened when I tried  screen.  It still does not appear to persist between ssh sessions.  Thanks,

Comment: "By default, ps selects all processes ... associated with the same terminal as the invoker.". If you run a remote ps from a new ssh session, the remote session has nothing to do with the previous ssh session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see your output with `ps -ax | grep inotify`.

`man ps` with the `a` and `x` flags defined respectively.

> Lift the BSD-style "only yourself" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like. The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by other means. An alternate description is that this option causes ps to list all processes with a terminal (tty), or to list all processes when used together with the x option

> Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like. The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by other means. An alternate description is that this option causes ps to list all processes owned by you (same EUID as ps), or to list all processes when used together with the a option.